# Initialization of RMSPROP optimizer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow RMSPROP optimizer can be used with **tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer** function as follows (This is relevant to tensorflow version 1.4).

```
tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(
    learning_rate, decay=0.9, momentum=0.0, epsilon=1e-10, use_locking=False,
    centered=False, name='RMSProp'
)
```

But it doesn't convey how to initialize *moving average of the squared gradient for each weight*. How does tensorflow initialize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tensorflow github repository, it has used **ones initializer** for to initialize moving average of the squared gradient for each weight.

Check the following of tensorflow version 1.4

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py